# Coordinates of a point under a reflection

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have the line $y=2x$ as my line of reflection and have the point $(2, -8.5)$, How do I find its point of reflection in the Cartesian Coordinate system? Khan Academy doesn't seem to give an explanation about that although it asks it in the exercises it gives for the topic.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a short cut of finding the point of reflection $(h,k)$ of $(x_1,y_1)$ in  the line $ax+by+c=0$, it is,

$\dfrac{(h-x_1)}{a}=\dfrac{(k-y_1)}{b}=-2\dfrac{|ax_1+by_1+c|}{a^2+b^2}$

This shortcut is derived by shifting the point along its $\perp$ to the given line by a distance of double of its $\perp$  distance to the line by using distance form.

Putting the given values, where equation of the line is $2x-y=0$

$\dfrac{(h-2)}{2}=\dfrac{(k-(-8.5))}{-1}=-2\dfrac{|2(2)-(-8.5)+0|}{(-2)^2+1^2}$

The required point comes out to be, $(-8,-3.5)$

---

And if you want to find the foot of $\perp$ from the point to the line you can apply,

$\dfrac{(h-x_1)}{a}=\dfrac{(k-y_1)}{b}=-\dfrac{|ax_1+by_1+c|}{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to match Khan's

Comment: I will post a screenshot of the actual problem.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer I've confirmed the shortcut.

Comment: What if I find a perpendicular line to $y=2x$ that contains the point $(2, -8.5)$ hen find where they intersect, find their distance, and then go that distance in the opposite direction to plot the point's reflection about it?

Comment: yes you are right! but my shortcut covers it all. "Its a well tested ,certified formula" for finding the point of reflection and if you want to find the foot of perpendicular you can just remove 2

Comment: Your shortcut isn't as intuitive so I will try this method on another problem. It isn't your fault, I am just not on that level yet.

Comment: you can apply it on any question related to point of reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The reflection of the point $(2, -8.5)$ in the line $y = 2x$ lies on the line perpendicular to $y = 2x$ that passes through the point $(2, -8.5)$.  Since the product of the slopes of non-vertical perpendicular lines is $-1$, a line perpendicular to the line $y = 2x$ will have slope $-1/2$.  The perpendicular line that passes through the point $(2, -8.5)$ has point-slope equation

\begin{align*}
y - (-8.5) & = -\frac{1}{2}(x - 2)\\
y + 8.5 & = -\frac{1}{2}(x - 2)
\end{align*}

To find where the two lines intersect, we solve the system of equations
\begin{align*}
y & = 2x\tag{1}\\
y + 8.5 & = -\frac{1}{2}(x - 2)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Substituting $2x$ for $y$ in equation 2 yields
\begin{align*}
2x + 8.5 & = -\frac{1}{2}(x - 2)\\
4x + 17 & = -(x - 2)\\
4x + 17 & = -x + 2\\
5x & = -15\\
x & = -3
\end{align*}
Substituting $-3$ in equation 1 yields $y = -6$.  As you can check, the point $(-3, -6)$ satisfies both equations, so it is on both the line $y = 2x$ and the line perpendicular to $y = 2x$ that passes through the point $(2, -8.5)$.

The point where the lines intersect is the midpoint of the segment connecting $(2, -8.5)$ with its reflection in the line $y = 2x$.  Hence, if $(x, y)$ represents the coordinates of the reflection of point $(2, -8.5)$ in the line $y = 2x$, then

$$\left(\frac{x + 2}{2}, \frac{y + -8.5}{2}\right) = (-3, -6)$$

Solving for the coordinates of the point of reflection yields
\begin{align*}
\frac{x + 2}{2} & = -3 & \frac{y - 8.5}{2} & = -6\\
x + 2 & = -6 & y - 8.5 & = -12\\
x & = -8 & y & = -3.5
\end{align*}

In the diagram below, the reflection of point $P(2, -8.5)$ in the line $y = 2x$ is the point $P'(-8, -3.5)$.  Note that point $M(-3, -6)$ is both the point where the line $y = 2x$ intersects the segment $\overline{PP'}$, which is perpendicular to the line $y = 2x$, and the midpoint of $\overline{PP'}$.[image: reflection_of_a_point_in_a_line]